Is this patent still active/legal?
This question is in regards to patent US7975953B2 To me this looks expired, but in legal "patent-terms" i'm not sure what that would mean.

Is it still active?
Is it then leagal world wide or just US?
Could i design and manufacture a product with similar design/mechanics and sell?
(NOT a direct copy of course)


What patent are you referring to?  Providing a link is most helpful.

Sorry. Here you go. Thanks! https://patents.google.com/patent/US7975953B2/en

I edited your question to include a link to the patent and updated my answer.

The document you linked is US patent US7815866B2. I've updated my answer to be specific to that.


Is it still active?


Generally patents are active for 20 years from the filing date. Ordinarily you would expect this patent to expire on 8-15-2028. However, to maintain a patent there are required periodic fees that need to be paid. This patent has been expired due to non-payment of maintenance fees. It might be theoretically possible for the owner of the patent to resurrect the patent and I'm not an expert at that.


Is it then legal world wide or just US?


The cited document is a US patent. A US patent is only for the US. There are no "Worldwide" patents but there are world applications. It is common for someone to file for patents in multiple countries for the same invention so you have to check for equivalents. It looks like a WO application was applied for but patents were never issued.


Could i design and manufacture a product with similar design/mechanics
and sell? (NOT a direct copy of course)


The patent cited has expired so it shouldn't keep you from commercializing a product. This doesn't mean there aren't other patents that are an issue. Assuming a patent is active, then what matters are the claims. To infringe on a patent you must implement each and every step in at least one claim. Understanding claims is tricky for lay people so it is often best to get a lawyer to perform a "freedom to operate" analysis. Also understand that avoiding infringement of a single patent does not insure non-infringement of all patents. A good way to proceed when you find a patent of concern is the review the other patents citing or cited by the patent. Google Patents will display these.
I would like to point out that I am not a lawyer so this isn't legal advice.

Sorry no link i see. Here you go. Thanks! https://patents.google.com/patent/US7975953B2/en

Hi. This was really helpful, and i learned a lot from it! Appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

@the_dragon_no1 You can upvote the answer and/or accept it if you like it. That’s how this site works.
